# How to move multiples files to remote server using rsync?

Tags: linux, rsync, backup

I'm using rsync to make incremental backups in my server and i created a bash script for it:
in practice it can copy multiple files at once into the local machine with ssh, and the syntax that i used is:
`rsync -aPhv --del user@host:/home/john/files :/home/steve/data  local_backup_dir`

which can copy multiple files at once.
My problem comes when i have to **restore** the backup, in fact i don't known how to move multiple files to different directory at the same time.
Due to i'm creating a bash script, i don't want duplicate the `rsync` commands multiple times

So my final question is: there's a way to copy **multiple** local files to different location at the same time using `rsync`?

Comment: Yeah i just noticed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the command that you use to create the backups you can solve your restore question with a single command.

Use this for backups:

```
rsync -aPhvR --del user@host:/home/./john/files :/home/./steve/data  local_backup_dir
```

And this for restore:

```
rsync -aPhvuR local_backup_dir/ user@host:/home/
```

What you would be doing here is creating `john/files` and `steve/data` under your `local_backup_dir` instead of just `files` and `data`. This way it's possible to apply them back to the remote system's `/home` in one operation.

Comment: Ok, your answer make sense but what would happend if a had to backup content from different path? Something like ```/home/john/files``` and ```/var/www/hostx.net/html```? The syntax used to restore(```rsync -aPhvR --del local_backup_dir/ user@host:/home/john/files :/var/www/hostx.net/html```)seems to not working

Comment: @icebit with the `-R` flag paths have to be relative. For your backup to a common target that means you'd need to backup `home/john/files` and `var/www/hostx.net/html`

Comment: Ok it works! ...btw i give me some errors like ```failed to set times on "/home": Operation not permitted (1)``` which prevents rsync to restore the other files.

Comment: @icebit if you're getting errors setting times on `/home` then your user account simply doesn't have the necessary privileges. (`/home` is typically owned by `root`.) But this error in itself won't stop `rsync` continuing - it's really only a warning.